# MATLAB:how to summarize the ones in an vector?

Tags: matlab, vector, count, split, zero

For example:

a=[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0];

Now i want to sum only the ones which are divides by the zeros:

ones=[2 2 3] - That means two ones,then we have 2 zeros which we do not count,then again two ones etc.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I would suggest finding all places where it *switches* from 0 to 1 and then finding all places where it switches from 1 to 0, and using those indices to find those lengths. The problem arises at the edges where if the first entry is 1, it doesn't *switch* to one from zero, and if the last entry is 1, we never find it because nothing switches to 0 at the end. In order to avoid this problem easily, we can add a 0 in the beginning and one at the end. This way we're guaranteed to find each one of those bursts of ones. In essence:

```
b = [0 a 0];
d = diff(b);

posEdge = find(d==1);
negEdge = find(d==-1);

countOnes = negEdge - posEdge
```